# Python does not finding installed library

Tags: python, macos

I have recently come across to this error:

```
~/Works/PolymerAnimation/PDF_try » python3 slope.py                                                       marco@MPB-2^Q5Ghz-16Gb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slope.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/Works/PolymerAnimation/PDF_try » pip3 install numpy                                                     marco@MPB-2^Q5Ghz-16Gb
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.18.0)
```

I have a 2012 macbook pro and since today I never have problem using python, I have also installed numpy using homebrew (package manager for mac) ... I don't know what's going on! Numpy is not a unique module that is give me this problem ... but all the module .. like matplotlib and so on!

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install numpy `

Comment: what does `python3 --version` output? also are you sure `pip3` is pointing to the `python3` environment, it's possible it is not

Comment: thanks @IainShelvington it solve my problem  !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **python3** and **pip3** are pointing to two different python versions. That's what caused the problem.

According to Iain's answer-

```
python3 -m pip install package_name
```

should solve the problem.